# Start a Command Prompt and then change the title of it via batch file?

Tags: batch, batch-file, batch-rename

I'm trying to start a command prompt via a batch file, `echo` some text, and change the title of the command prompt. I'm trying:

```
start cmd
/k echo This is a terminal
/k title Terminal
```

The echo text displays, but not the title text.

Answer (score 5):

The [TITLE](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SettingTheTitleOfTheDOSCommandPromptFromABatchFile.aspx) command works for me.

```
start cmd
TITLE Test
PAUSE
```

Edit: I believe the syntax for /k is

```
cmd /k "TITLE Test"
```

Answer (score 3):

Silly me, I've found what I needed.

Doing

```
start "title here"
```

will do a title for the wanted program. From there, it is just

```
start "Terminal" cmd /k echo This is a terminal
```

If you want to run multiple echos / other commands, do

```
start "Terminal" cmd /k "echo this is one echo command & echo this is another"
```

where you separate each command input with `&`

Comment: -1  Even after you correct yourself, your quotes are a mess and wrong, Try `start "Terminal" cmd /k echo This is a terminal`  or `start "Terminal" "cmd /k echo This is a terminal"`

Comment: @barlop whoops your right. edited.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following:

```
start cmd /k "echo this is a terminal & title Terminal"
```

The ampersand allows you to put multiple commands on one command line - see [Command shell overview](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds_shelloverview.mspx?mfr=true).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `start "Terminal Name Here" C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe` because it only opens 1 window while `start "Terminal" cmd /k echo This is a terminal` will keep opening windows over and over again until it is forced to stop IF you name it `cmd.cmd` or `cmd.bat`.

Comment: `will keep opening windows...` - uhm - it does not, except you're mad enough to name your script `cmd.bat` or `cmd.cmd`.

Comment: really? oops my fault. thanks for letting me know @Stephan